# Нужно ли здесь тире? Вместо тире можно подставить «а именно»

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли здесь тире?
Вместо тире можно подставить «а именно».

> Инженерная работа в области строительства — дефектовки: оборудования, фланцевых соединений, опорных конструкций и т.п.

Answer (score 3):

Может быть, такой вариант подойдет:

Инженерная работа в области строительства: дефектовка оборудования, фланцевых соединений, опорных конструкций и т.п.

(Дефектовка - определение причины неисправности какого-либо оборудования, оценка его годности специалистом).

Comment: Это был первоначальный вариант, но тут тогда должно слово дефектовка стоять после каждой запятой. дефектовка оборудования, дефектовка, фланцевых, дефектовка ...

Comment: А почему? Дефектовка (чего?), а далее следует однородный ряд дополнений, не требуется повтора слова "дефектовка".

Comment: Спасибо, что то я замудрил)